# Why are Hope and Janet's surname's van Dyne and not Pym?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man-2015, ant-man-and-the-wasp

Janet and Hope's surnames in the MCU are van Dyne yet Hank's is Pym. Janet is married to Hank and Hope is their daughter. It is usually the case that a wife will take their husband's surname upon marriage and the daughter will then take that name as well.

I've seen the theory that Janet didn't take Hank's surname when they married which is entirely possible but there's no direct/explicit mention of this that I can find.

The theory on Hope is also that either she has always been a van Dyne after her mother or she changed it from Pym after her mother's "death" and her father becoming distant in a way to honour her mother and distance herself from her father.

> **Hope van Dyne:** You know when my mother died I didn’t see him for two weeks?
>
> **Scott Lang:** He was in grief.
>
> **Hope van Dyne:** Yeah, so was I, and I was seven. And he never came back, not in any way that counted. He just sent me off to boarding school.
>
> <sub>*Ant-Man*</sub>

However, there is no direct/explicit evidence I can find which back either these up except informed speculation.

**Why do they have different names?**

Comment: *"It is usually the case that a wife will take their husband's surname upon marriage and the daughter will then take that name as well."* - Not always. agreed it's common but many women prefer to keep their maiden names....especially in the US.

Comment: @Paulie_D In the UK it's pretty standard and I always thought that was true of the US too but happy to learn something.

Comment: I'm in the UK and even here it's becoming more common for women to retain their original names. Many women are now "double barrelling" but *van Dyne Pym* is a little awkward. Plus, as a respected scientist in her own right (at least in the MCU) she would be expected to go by her own name in many cases.

Comment: Janet is from a very rich and prominent family. It is likely she wanted to keep her surname over the somewhat nondescript "Pym". Another factor is that when Janet married Hank, he was in the identity of Yellowjacket, who was then not generally known to be Hank.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Yellowjacket in the MCU is only Darren Cross no? Unless I'm completely missing something.

Comment: Ah - I missed that it was MCU rather than the comics.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The UK *does* have a [rather prominent counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II), though

Comment: @Chronocidal Royalty isn't exactly the common situation.

Comment: Also worth noting that one of the common trains women might keep their last name after marriage is if they already have a career/title under that name. Janet, being a practicing scientist, might not want to create confusion over papers she'd authored, etc.

Comment: On top of what Fuzzy Boots said about Janet. For ope, it may speak to Hank's absenteeism as a father. In the US when creating a birth certificate the mother and father both must sign off on the name if the surname does not match the mother's (although I believe this is a more recent law). So it is possible that Hank was not there when Hope was born therefore could not give his surname to Hope.

Comment: @Chronocidal: you mean II is her maiden name??

Comment: 1) Out here in a rural area of Canada (ie: not a cutting-edge trendsetting spot), I run my mind over all the married folks I know and nearly 50% of couples don't do that antiquated name change custom. 2) In "Ant Man", Hope is clearly angry and estranged with her father.  Switching to her mother's name would be Job #1 as soon as it was legally allowed.

Comment: While it has become fairly common in the US for women not to take their husband's surname, that is a relatively recent phenomenon. It was reasonably rare in the 1990's when Hope would have been born, and even less common before that when Hank & Janet would have been married. Hope may have changed her name back after her mother's death and estrangement from her father, however - that did happen to some family on my wife's side.

Comment: My first wife (married 1982) never used my surname, though if we'd had children, they'd have legally had my name.  If Hope was born before they were married, however, she'd have had Hank's name only if she chose to take it or if he legally adopted her.

Comment: @FreeMan, while it may not have been common, it was well-known for happening. Among people where name recognition was important, such as actors, many women maintained the use of their own name. After all, have you ever heard of noted sex symbol and actress Marilyn Miller? How about Marilyn DiMaggio?

Answer (score 2):

Janet van Dyne keeps her maiden name, as some women do.

In the MCU, Hope is estranged from her father after her mother's death and adopts her mother's maiden name.

In the comics, there is no Hope van Dyne, and the movie character is based on Janet van Dyne, Hope Pym, and Nadia van Dyne

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold statements?